# Hide Html Off Specific Values in ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have an online store through volusion that I really do not want to start from scratch to make myself.

They do limit a lot of the necessary back-end code to make any edits. I do believe it is written using ASP.NET.

What I have is a discount that removes a charge. In the shopping cart, it shows this discount and I want it hidden. If I had access to the raw html, I would just add in a class but that isnt an option. My problem is that if I manipulate any specific CSS for these values, it impacts a real discount that I would want the customer to see as it uses the same class.

```
<b>Removed Travel Surcharge [item1]</b>

<b>10% Off</b>
```

I would want the "Removed Travel Surcharge" line hidden if the value equals that. Is this something that can be done with JS or something? It just looks unappealing.

I can add some raw code in the footer template etc.

Comment: You say that you want to remove "the line". What line? Is there an element (e.g. a div) that contains that whole line? Can you show more context for the HTML code that you want to hide? If necessary, look at the page source given by the browser or by an F12 tool.

Comment: The structure is:
<div>
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <b>Removed Travel Surcharge [item1]</b>
    </td>
    <td>
     <b>10% Off</b>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>

Comment: They do not have specific classes or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the element's style locally

```
<b style="display: none;">Removed Travel Surcharge [item1]</b>
```

Comment: This is a value that is automatically generated. It sure would be easier, but I am limited on what I have access to modify. I would need some logic to simply hide the value if it equaled the set value.

Comment: That is literally the only code I have access to. The outputted html as I provided. I can through some code in the header or footer, but they do have me pretty limited on what I can modify. Just compare this to a basic wordpress template and I can only access the Editor, except that this is not coded in PHP)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to edit the template_XXX.html file (in the admin panel under Design/FileEditor).  In the JQuery .ready() function, you'll add some JS/jquery to either hide that element or set the html to blank.  Here's a simple example that I wrote to hide the text of the Top Sellers homepage section...

```
`$('b:contains("Top Sellers")').html("");`
```

Just in case you're unaware, that template file is loaded for every page in your store, so you can access/edit all the rendered HTML through it.